# Prevent default behavior back button in NavigationBar

Tags: sencha-touch-2, back-button, navigationbar

Is it true that when the back button is taped, the current view is destroyed?
If so how can I prevent this?

I'm getting this idea because if I set an active item (item gotten by using Ext.getCmp) on the navigation view, tap on the back button and then set the active item again, the Ext.getCmp returns undefined.

Any ideas, solutions or workarounds for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property autoDestroy is responsible for that. Note that it should be set for Navigator and affect on the children destroying, not to the Navigator itself. If it set to true - all poped items would be destroyed by back action, otherwise will be kept in memory

Cheers, Oleg